# Join of two varieties construction via rational maps.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, grassmannian

Consider the map $j: X\times Y \to\mathbb{G}(1,n), \ ([v],[w])\mapsto [v\wedge w]$ i.e. sending two points to their line where $X$ and $Y$ are two projective irreducible varieties. I would like to prove that this map is rational. When $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, this map is obviously regular and thus also rational due to the nature of the Pluecker Coordinates.

If $X\neq Y$, then we can look at the open subset $X\times Y \setminus (X\cap Y)\times (X\cap Y)$. As $X\neq Y$, this is a non-empty subset and as $X$ and $Y$ are irreducible, it is also dense. This open set, however, was already covered above as you simply get varietes that are disjoint and thus you get a regular map. This means that $j$ is rational in this case.

Now, the case I am struggling on is $X=Y$. Why is $j: X\times X\to \mathbb{G}(1,n)$ rational? I have failed to come up with a suitable non-empty open subset unfortunately. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it regular outside the diagonal?

Comment: What you are saying, however, is that the diagonal itself is closed. Correct? As we would thus get a nonempty open set. However, the diagonal is closed iff $X$ is Hausdorff. But the Zariski Topology isn't Hausdorff in general. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Or do you want to restrict $j$ to an open subset that is contained in the complement of the diagonal? I think that would work somehow. However, the question arises what happens to this space when $X$ is simply one point? Then we can't neglect the diagonal. How do you resolve that?

Comment: For projective varieties the diagonal is closed.

Comment: Yes, I have overseen that. But what about the case that $X$ is one point?

Comment: In the case when $X$ is a point, the map is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "Consider the map $j: X\times Y \to\mathbb{G}(1,n), \ ([v],[w])\mapsto [v\wedge w]$ i.e. sending two points to their line where $X$ and $Y$ are two projective irreducible varieties. I would like to prove that this map is rational. When $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, this map is obviously regular and thus also rational due to the nature of the Pluecker Coordinates."

**Answer:** If $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}(V^*), Y \subseteq \mathbb{P}(W^*)$ and if $x:=[l] \in X, y:=[l']\in Y$ with $l \subseteq V, l' \subseteq W$ non-zero lines, it follows the "wedge product" $[l \wedge l']$ is not well defined. The lines $l,l'$ live in different vector spaces and cannot be "wedged together". Hence the map $j$ does not exist.

If $E$ is an $A$-module, you may form the module $\wedge^n E$ of $E$ with itself $n$-times. If $E$ is generated by one element $e$ it follows $E \wedge_A E=(0)$ is zero. Hence if $A$ is a field and $l\subseteq E$ is a line it follows $l \wedge l=(0)$ is zero.

**Note:** If $X:=\mathbb{G}(m,n)$ is the grassmannian of $m$-planes $W\subseteq V\cong \mathbb{C}^n$ in an $n$-dimensional complex vector space, $V$ it follows the exterior product $\wedge^m W \subseteq \wedge^m V$ is a line in $\wedge^m V$. This gives the Plucker embedding

$$p: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(\wedge^m V^*)$$

defined by $p([W]):=[\wedge^m W]$. Here you wedge a vector space $W$ with itself. You cannot wedge two vector spaces $W \wedge V$.

Comment: I don't understand.$X$ and $Y$ live in the same projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$; so why would their line not be defined? So $j$ is a well-defined map (e.g. look at the case where $X$ is one point: You get the cone). Right?

Comment: @EdwardTeach - The wedge product is defined as $\wedge^n E:=E^{\otimes_k n}/I$ where $I \subseteq E^{\otimes_k n}$ is a certain submodule. You cannot define $E \wedge F$ for two differing modules $E,F$. Hence if $X,Y \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_k$ and if $[u]\in X, [v]\in Y$, it follows the wedge product $u \wedge v$ is undefined.